# Even fibonacci numbers in a "given" range

Tags: java

This code works perfectly when the start value is 0, 1. But what if I wanted to specify the start value like the end value? instead of 0-500 = 188; We put 18-500 = ?; Ultimately create a method that takes a start and end value for the range.

```
int evenFibSum(int limit)
{
    if (limit < 2)
        return 0;

    long ef1 = 0, ef2 = 2;
    long sum = ef1 + ef2;

    while (ef2 <= limit)
    {

        long ef3 = 4 * ef2 + ef1;


        if (ef3 > limit)
            break;


        ef1 = ef2;
        ef2 = ef3;
        sum += ef2;
    }

    return(int) sum;
}


public static void main (String[] args) 
{
    int limit = 500;
    System.out.println(evenFibSum(limit));

}
```

Here is what I have tried to implement:

```
    long startRange;, evenFib1;;
    long sum = startRange + evenFib1;

    if (startRange == 0)
    {
        startRange += 1;
    } 
    else if (startRange % 2 == 0)
    {
      evenFib1 + 2;
    }
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If generating Fibonacci numbers works from 0 to n, then generate them all, and take only the ones that you want. For example:

```
int []f = fibonacciNumbers(500); //suppose this gives you first 500 fibonacci numbers
```

If you want numbers between 18th and 500th number you can just take that part of the array.

```
int []f2 = new int[500-18];

for(int i=0; i<(500-18); i++){
   f2[i] = f[18+i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs only to check for ef2, as you do with limit:

```
long evenFibSumBetween(int start, int limit)
{
    if (limit < 2)
        return 0;

    long ef1 = 0, ef2 = 2;
    long sum = 0;
    if (start <= ef2)
        ef1 + ef2;

    while (ef2 <= limit)
    {  
        long ef3 = 4 * ef2 + ef1;
        if (ef3 > limit)
            break;
        ef1 = ef2;
        ef2 = ef3;
        if (start <= ef2)
            sum += ef2;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

However this would be the same as the slower:

```
long evenFibSumBetween(int start, int limit) {
    return evenFibSub(limit) - evenFibSum(start - 1);
}
```